# Search document.innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a way to search the generated source of a webpage ( document.innerHTML) for a string, in javascript.

I wouldn't want to use window.find() since i might have to look for id's or names too.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: any string? specific id's? tag names?

Comment: yeah..it could be any string.. something like "searchstring" or sth like "id='myId'" ..

Answer (score 12):

`document.innerHTML` is undefined
`var source = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
var found = source.search("searchString");`

Comment: this definitely works for a normal string. But, when you have to search something like id="'myId'" , this doesnt seem to work.

Comment: kambamsu - please don't use innerHTML to search for HTML. Use the DOM! That's what it's meant for...

Comment: @J-P: Kambansu wants to search everything, including ids, classes, attributes. It can be done using DOM, but that would be complex huh?

Comment: @kambamsu, if you're searching for id="myId" then you have to escape the string, or switch the quotes.  Html requires the doubles quotes. So your search string would have to look like "id=\"myId\""

Comment: N 1.1, James: perhaps it DOM is intended for these things, or perhaps html is simpler, but in order to pick the best advise: which of those aproaches do you think would be faster?

Answer (score 1):

You could use an indexOf function to search string

```
var source = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
var foundIndex = source.indexOf(searchString);
```

OR 
using regular expression,

```
var paragraph = 'The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog. It barked. ';
var regex = /quick/g;
var found = paragraph.match(regex);
```

ECMAScript 6

```
"hello".startsWith("ello", 1) // true
"hello".endsWith("hell", 4)   // true
"hello".includes("ell")       // true
"hello".includes("ell", 1)    // true
"hello".includes("ell", 2)    // false
```

Answer (score 0):

try jQuery [selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Will match elements based on the limited set of conditions that can be expressed with selectors. It won't match strings.